# How to verify date format using selenium2

Tags: selenium, testng, selenium-webdriver

Can any one will let me know how to verify the email and date format with selenium webdriver using TestNG?

Comment: Which programming language do you write your tests in?

Comment: Which language Java or Python or Ruby .....?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String REGEX = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"; 

//You may find anyother pattern for a valid email. Choose the one which you feel better
```

Then in Selenium,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.Id("yourId"));
```

Check like this,

```
assertTrue(element.getText().matches(REGEX));
```

or you may have this REGEX in testng.xml and use it by @Paramaters in your test class. Choice is yours. For this visit [getting parametrs from testng.xml](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Parameters.html)